# How to cross join two tables in SQL server

Tags: sql-server-2005, join

HI
I have a table EMP_SCHED which contains COMMENTS  Column for EMP_ID and another table SHIFT which also contains COMMENTS column for EMP_ID.Now for a given date range I need to pick COMMNETS from both tables .

For example in I have 7 EMP_IDs in EMP_SCHED table and 2 EMPIDs in SHIFT .I need all the EMPIDS and COMMNETNS and place the comments for common EMPID from both tables in single row

I thought of  place join first on EMP_SCHED then on SHIFT but they returned multiple rows

```
   SELECT distinct E.[EMP_ID]as SCHED_EMP,S.EMP_ID as SHIFT_EMP,
          E.[SCHED_COMMENT],S.COMMENTS     
  FROM [EMP_SCHED_COMMENT] E, SHIFT S
  where e.emp_id =*s.emp_id
```

The output looked

```
NULL    33018   NULL    Truck Delivery
NULL    33029   NULL    Order Beer/Wine
NULL    33067   NULL    Deli Shift Available
NULL    33115   NULL    Clean backroom
NULL    34232   NULL    ccccc
34020   34020       kkkkkk
34020   34020       looo
```

Am I doing correct here ?
Also MY SQL SERVER is not allowing keywords LFET RIGHT when used for joins

(An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'LEFT')

Answer (score 2):

first get a distinct list of the ids

```
SELECT DISTINCT EMP_ID
FROM EMP_SCHED
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT EMP_ID
FROM SHIFT
```

then link the original tables.

How can you not use LEFT JOINS?

This works in sql server 2005

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE(
        EmpID INT,
        Comment VARCHAR(MAX)
)

DECLARE @Shift TABLE(
        Emp_ID INT,
        Comment VARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @Employee (EmpID,Comment) SELECT 1, 'Emp1'
INSERT INTO @Employee (EmpID,Comment) SELECT 2, 'Emp2'
INSERT INTO @Employee (EmpID,Comment) SELECT 3, 'Emp3'

INSERT INTO @Shift (Emp_ID,Comment) SELECT 2, 'Shift2'
INSERT INTO @Shift (Emp_ID,Comment) SELECT 3, 'Shift3'
INSERT INTO @Shift (Emp_ID,Comment) SELECT 4, 'Shift4'

SELECT  *
FROM    (
            SELECT  DISTINCT 
                    EmpID
            FROM    @Employee
            UNION
            SELECT  DISTINCT
                    Emp_ID
            FROM    @Shift
        ) EmpIDs LEFT JOIN
        @Employee e ON EmpIDs.EmpID = e.EmpID LEFT JOIN
        @Shift s ON EmpIDs.EmpID = s.Emp_ID
```

Comment: I had used but what if the column names are difernet for both.What happend in my casse is its picking values from my first table only

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EMP_SCHED.COMMENTS, SHIFT.COMMENTS 
FROM EMP_SCHED LEFT OUTER JOIN SHIFT ON
EMP_SCHED.EMP_ID = SHIFT.EMP_ID
WHERE 
[(YOUR DATE RANGE FILTER)]
```

IN SQL Server syntax for cross join is TABLE1 CROSS JOIN TABLE2..

AND Left join is infact LEFT OUTER JOIN AND RIGHT OUTER JOIN IS RIGHT OUTER JOIN. I'm not sure LEFT and/or RIGHT is the proper syntax.

Comment: From your question I don't see you need a cross join.

Comment: I tried using cross join but not working one because SQLSERVR2005 is expecteing else can u suggest something like =* if any for cross join